# Dividing summed field by another summed field in the same query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

How to divide a summed field by another summed field in the same query.

Example: lets have the query "querySummary" which its field have been grouped already

```
  SID      SumOfCredits     SumOfMarks
  1            3                18
  2            2                20
  3            4                40
Group By      Sum               Sum
```

I want to add another field named "FAvg" to the same query that builds up of dividing "SumOfMarks" by SumOfCredits, so the the result should be as following

```
SID      SumOfCredits     SumOfMarks      FAvg
1            3                18           6
2            2                20           10
3            2                40           20
```

Any help please ? many Thanks

Comment: Can you share your actual query please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace "Sum" in the "Total" row by "Expression" and in the "Field" row use the expression:

```
FAvg: Sum(Mark)/Sum(Credit)
```

You'll get something like this:
[image]

(The other `Sum` columns are not required for the `FAvg` expression)

The SQL looks like this:

```
SELECT
    Table1.SID,
    Sum(Table1.Credit) AS SumOfCredit,
    Sum(Table1.Mark) AS SumOfMark,
    Sum([Mark])/Sum([Credit]) AS FAvg
FROM
    Table1
GROUP BY
    Table1.SID;
```